# How is the entire memoize cache deleted in lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash, memoization

When using `_.memoize` from `lodash`, is it possible to delete the entire cache?

I have seen a few discussions on github:
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1269
https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/265

But I'm still not 100% clear on how this would be approached, if you wanted to do a page wide cache clear? Is the intention to set it to a WeakMap first, then call clear as required?

Comment: Just call `memoize` again and overwrite your memoised function, and the cache is gone.

Comment: I want to remove all/entire memorize' cached functions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lodash doesn't provide a way to delete cache of all memoized functions. You have to do it one by one. It's because every memoized function has its own cache object instance.

Look at lodash `memoize` [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.2/lodash.js#L10539):

```
function memoize(func, resolver) {
  var memoized = function() {
    // ...
  }
  memoized.cache = new (memoize.Cache || MapCache);
  return memoized;
}
```

The GitHub discussions you referred to are about clearing cache of a single memoized function.

You can keep all memoized functions into an array so that it's able to iterate over them and clear cache one by one.

```
const func1 = _.memoize(origFunc1);
const func2 = _.memoize(origFunc2);

const memoizedFunctions = [];
memoizedFunctions.push(func1);
memoizedFunctions.push(func2);   

// clear cache of all memoized functions
memoizedFunctions.forEach(f => f.cache = new _.memoize.Cache);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, but in Typescript i had to do: `f.cache = new (_.memoize.Cache as any)` as the compiler refused to do the _new_ otherwise. Might be something wrong with my version of the typings for lodash.

Comment: It should indeed be `new _.memoize.Cache`

Answer (score 11):

update answer in 2019 :), lodash has added clear function to cache method so the way to clear cache can be

`memoizedFunctions.forEach(f => f.cache.clear());`

tested lodash version 4.17.13

Answer (score 4):

```
function _printName(name) {
  console.log(name);
}

const printName = _.memoize(_printName);

printName("David");
printName("John");
```

To clear the entire memoized cache (both David and John):

```
printName.cache.clear();
```

To explicitly remove a single memoized object:

```
printName.cache.delete("David");
```